# Refreshing a ListView automatically in android as Pull Down to Refresh functionality of iPhone

Tags: android

I have a problem as, I am creating an app as a social networking app in which there are posts from users, these posts are shown in a listview but the posts are updated only when we recall the same activity because parsing is mandatory for the same. I want that the listview should be automatically refreshed when we pull down the same as iPhone Pull Down to Refresh functionality. I don't know how to implement the same. Please suggest me for the right solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about a chat like Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find example same for Pull to refresh over here.

https://github.com/guillep/PullToRefresh/downloads

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You must be having a background Thread /Service that fetches posts from the internet.You can implement a custom Observe-Notify event pattern. Service/Thread will implement custom notifier, Activity will implement custom Listener.When activity starts, it will register itself to Notifier, When posts arrive, Service will call notify and pass the posts object,Activity will get notified , it will update the adapter for list and call notifyDataSetChanged() method on the list adapter.